# Finding the contact force in a mechanical problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, statics

what is the proper FBD for this system. I cant decide since the weight is given, but there is tension and contact forces. Things get mixed up.

Determine the contact force between the smooth 200-lb ball B and the
horizontal bar, and the magnitude of the pin reaction at A. Neglect the weights of
the bar and the pulley.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! I'm afraid that the FAQ is very clear that these kinds of "Here is a basic problem, please show me the solution" questions [are off topic](http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). If you can re-formulate this question in terms of the principles at work you could get it re-opened. Of course, if you expressed it in terms of the basic principle you'd probably see the answer right away. Hint: are the masses, $B$ and $C$, under acceleration? What does that say about the sum of the forces acting on them?

Answer (score 1):

Use two conditions: 1. The sum of forces acting on B (T,N,mg) is zero; 2. The sum of moments of forces (T at C, N at B) applied to the pin with respect to point A is zero. Choose the signs carefully.